# Loop through JSON data and get event information

Tags: jquery, json

```
 {
"events": [
    {
        "summary": {
            "total_items": 2135,
            "first_event": 5242051116,
            "last_event": 5242051116,
            "filters": {
                "keywords": "Atlanta"
            },
            "num_showing": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "event": {
            "box_header_text_color": "FFFFFF",
            "locale": "en_US",
            "link_color": "990066",
            "box_background_color": "FFFFFF",
            "box_border_color": "FFE5F6",
            "timezone": "America/New_York",
            "organizer": {
                "url": "http://newyearsevedanceparty.eventbrite.com",
                "description": "We organize Swing, Latin & Ballroom Dinner & Dance events in and around the Gwinnett area.\r\n\"Bringing the Joy of Dance to you One Step at a Time\" \r\nhttp://www.dancing4fun.comhttp://www.meetup.com/dancing4fun\r\nSean-christopher770.855.4396",
                "long_description": "We organize Swing, Latin & Ballroom Dinner & Dance events in and around the Gwinnett area.\r\n\"Bringing the Joy of Dance to you One Step at a Time\" \r\nhttp://www.dancing4fun.comhttp://www.meetup.com/dancing4fun\r\nSean-christopher770.855.4396",
                "id": 249877987,
                "name": "Dancing4fun Dinner Dancing & Socializing"
            },
            "background_color": "FFE5F6",
            "id": 5242051116,
            "category": "music,entertainment",
            "box_header_background_color": "A2B8BF",
            "capacity": 0,
            "num_attendee_rows": null,
            "title": "Two Valentines Party in Atlanta!Valentines Day & Valentines Weekend Latin Dance party Atlanta Ga Thursday February 14, 2013 & Saturday February 16, 2013",
            "start_date": "2014-02-15 21:00:00",
            "status": "Live",
            "description": "<P STYLE=\"text-align: center;\"><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #ff0000;\"><STRONG><SPAN STYLE=\"font-size: large;\">Two Valentines Parties in Atlanta!!<BR>Hosted by Dancing4fun!<BR><BR>Valentines Day & Valentines Weekend Latin Dance party </SPAN></STRONG></SPAN><BR><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #ff0000;\"><STRONG><SPAN STYLE=\"font-size: large;\">Atlanta Ga <BR>Thursday February 14, 2013<BR>And<BR>Saturday February 16, 2013<BR><BR></SPAN></STRONG></SPAN><IMG SRC=\"https://evbdn.eventbrite.com/s3-s3/eventlogos/1669518/facebookcoverlatin.jpg\" ALT=\"\" WIDTH=\"519\" HEIGHT=\"132\"></P>\r\n<P></P>",
            "end_date": "2014-02-16 03:00:00",
            "tags": "Valentines Day party Atlanta Ga, Valentines Latin Dance party Gwinnett, Valentines Atlanta Ga, Valentines Day Dance party Suwanee Ga, latin dance Valentines Day party Gwinnett, Suwanee Dinner and Dance Valentines party, Romantic Valentines Day event atlan",
            "timezone_offset": "GMT-0500",
            "text_color": "990066",
            "repeat_schedule": "custom-5226372",
            "title_text_color": "",
            "tickets": [
                {
                    "ticket": {
                        "description": "",
                        "end_date": "2014-02-15 20:00:00",
                        "min": 1,
                        "max": null,
                        "price": "11.24",
                        "visible": "true",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "display_price": "10.00",
                        "type": 0,
                        "id": 16707094,
                        "include_fee": "false",
                        "name": "Thursday February 14, 2013 - Valentines Day Latin Night - Pay @ door"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ticket": {
                        "description": "",
                        "end_date": "2014-02-15 20:00:00",
                        "min": 1,
                        "max": null,
                        "price": "11.24",
                        "visible": "true",
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "display_price": "10.00",
                        "type": 0,
                        "id": 16707098,
                        "include_fee": "false",
                        "name": "Valentines Weekend Latin Night  - Saturday February 16, 2013 - pay @ door"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "distance": "0.00M",
            "created": "2013-01-14 23:02:15",
            "url": "http://latindancingvalentinesatlanta.eventbrite.com/?aff=SRCH",
            "box_text_color": "A2B8BF",
            "privacy": "Public",
            "modified": "2013-12-07 15:54:30",
            "repeats": "yes"
        }
    }
]
```

}

I am getting this json formatted data when I hit eventbrite api. I am trying to get, lets say title of each event using jquery.

tried a lot of things like

```
.done(function (response) {
    $.each(response.events, function(index, element){
        console.log(element['event'].title);
    });
});
```

but I get `TypeError: obj is undefined length = obj.length`

any help will be much appreciated. thanks

I know there are a lot of examples on here but i tried them and didnt work for my data  structure.

Comment: No need to yell in the subject. Please try to format your source as readable as possible.

Comment: maybe you need to use JSON.parse(response) before starting traversing.

Comment: Get the response in js array format first using  $.parseJSON function

Comment: This might a start for you http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/JPjmJ/

Comment: Try this: `console.log(typeof response);` before `$.each`. What do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of your nodes have an event property, so it's bound to fail out for those nodes. You have to check for the node existing first or you'll get an object ref error. Such as:

```
$.each(response.events, function(index, element){
    if(element['event']) {
        console.log(element['event'].title);
    }
});
```

See this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/eDV2Q/

Comment: thanks alot, i was able to get the title but the event can be multiple so how do i loop through each event and get the title? thanks again

Comment: You could do .each on the element['event']?

Comment: put this inside the if statement? i get undefined                              $.each(element['event'], function(ev){
                                       console.log(ev.title);
                                    });

Comment: You still need the if statement too, the if(element['event']) { before the new $.each

Comment: $.each(response.events, function(index, element){
                                   if(element['event']) {
                                    $.each(element['event'], function(ev){
                                       console.log(ev.title);
                                    });
                                  }
                                 });  still get the undefined

Comment: Can you update the jsFiddle with your new JSON data and code?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the first element:

```
    {
        "summary": {
            "total_items": 2135,
            "first_event": 5242051116,
            "last_event": 5242051116,
            "filters": {
                "keywords": "Atlanta"
            },
            "num_showing": 1
        }
    }
```

does not contain the "event" property...